# How to convert Array to String? Database show me Array keyword instead of String

Tags: php

How to convert Array to String?
I insert data into the database in the
form of an array. Mysql database show me Array keyword instead of String. I have multiple text boxes with the same name. [Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB2aX.png)

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','registeruserdb');
if(!$conn){
die("Failed to Connect. Contact Network Administrator");
}
  // insert Category into category table
  if (isset($_POST['submitbtn']))
{
   $name          = $_POST['Name'];
   $relationship  = $_POST['Relationship'];
   $cnic          = $_POST['Cnic'];
   $contact       = $_POST['Contact'];

   $query="INSERT INTO registeruser(name,relationship,cnic,contactnumber) VALUES('$name','$relationship','$cnic','$contact')";
      if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
       {
             echo '<script>
                            alert("Added successfully.");
                            window.location="index.php";
                   </script>';
         }
         else
        {
            echo '<script>alert("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. ") </script>';
        }
       }
 ?>
```

**Register Form:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="inc">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" required name="Name[]" placeholder="Name"/>
                <input type="text" required name="Relationship[]" placeholder="Relationship"/>
                <input type="text" required name="Cnic[]" placeholder="Cnic#"/>
                <input type="text" required name="Contact[]" placeholder="Contact#"/>
                <button style="margin-left: 50px" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="append" name="append">
                  Add Textbox</button>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submitbtn"/>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: your field is array, so loop through that array and insert one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to convert an array to string:

1. The simplest one is the [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function. This however can create problems when the delimiter you use is featured in any of the array-elements.
2. The second common method is [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). It's a common practice to store a serialized array as string in a database, but know that it can lead to some headaches if you want to commit extended searches in the future based on that field. However for simply reading the data, you can just [unseralize](https://www.php.net/unserialize) it.

But the best solution for this sort of problem is usually to create a table for your values with some foreign keys. It really depends on your intentions for the future: if you're expecting lots of records and you intend to query them a lot, I would really advise that method. If not, you can use the above methods to save some time.